# How to autocomplete in ggplot2 qplot() and geom_()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

`qplot()` and `geom_()` parameters don't include some parameters like color or shape ..etc

```
help(qplot)
help(geom_point)
```

However one can write the following code

```
qplot(x= price , data  = diamonds , color = cut)
```

I know all of these parameters are `aes()` parameters, But aes() also don't mention these parameters explicitly.

So how can one know if the parameter he is typing is correct if there is no auto-completion?

### Update:

Now I know that every geom_() function has it's own specified aesthetics in the documentation, but my question now is that why there is no autocomplete instead of opening the documentation. Is there is a way around that?

Comment: The parameters are documented in the documentation of the geoms (e.g., see under "Aesthetics" in `help("geom_bar")`. The documentation of `qplot` says which geoms are used by default.

Comment: That was helpful! but please check the update, why these is no autocompletion for these aesthetics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions, and many others in R make use of `...` to take arguments that aren't among the named arguments provided in the function definition. For example, looking at `geom_point`

```
args(geom_point)
#function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", position = "identity", 
#    ..., na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE)
```

`data` is a named argument, but `x` and `colour` aren't, so are 'soaked up' by the dots. Referring to the source code or the help file, you see that these arguments are passed to the `layer()` function.

The flexibility to pass these dots to different functions depending on other code within the function means that there's no general way to work out without running the code what the possible arguments are. **The only way to do this is via the help or source code.**

See `?dots` or `?'...'` for more about how the dots work.